# Multiplying alternating sign numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

How many answers would this have and why?
$\pm 5 $ X $\pm 5$

From what I can understand the answer would be

25 from multiplying 5 and 5

-25 from multiplying 5 and-5

25 from multiplying -5 and -5

-25 from multiplying -5 and 5

So I would say the answer would be: $\pm 5$

In a geometric series in which the constant multiplier is $\pm a number$ what would the series look like?

My teacher marks this series as this answer:

$\sum_{i=0}^5 -3/4(\pm3)^n -1 = -4/3, \pm,-12, \pm36  $

$\pm3$ should be to the n-1

I would think that the answer would be:

$-4/3, \pm 4,\pm12, \pm36  $

Why is this wrong if the $\pm number$ is multiplied by another $\pm number$?

Comment: Well, it's OK to have different signs when you multiply a $\pm\rm{number}$ by _another_ such number. But what if you multiply it by _the very same_ $\pm\rm{number}$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin, you said more eloquently what I tried to say rather clumsily.

Comment: That's an alternating series. For +3 it'll be positive for any n, for -3 it'll be positive for an even n and negative for an odd n. You need to take all of these cases into consideration when solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one says something like $\pm 5$, they mean it can take the value of $+5$ or it can take the value of $-5$.

Certainly, something like $(\pm 5)+ (\pm 5)$ could be interpreted as being one of any of the following: $(+5)+(+5),~~ (+5)+(-5),~~ (-5)+(+5),~~ (-5)+(-5)$ and so could take the values of $10, 0, -10$ for a total of three possibilities.

However, when written instead as $2\cdot (\pm 5)$ we do *not* interpret this the same as the previous line, but instead as $2\cdot (+5)$ or $2\cdot (-5)$, yielding only the possibilities $+10$ and $-10$ for a total of only two possibilities.

In the same way, $(\pm 5)^2$ should be thought of as either $(+5)^2$ or $(-5)^2$, both of which yield the result of $+25$ and not thought of as $(\pm 5)\cdot (\pm 5)$ which could yield the result of $+25$ or $-25$.

In general, $(\pm x)^n = \begin{cases} x^n&\text{if}~n~\text{even}\\ \pm(x^n)&\text{if}~n~\text{odd}\end{cases}$